# MenuInfo не передаётся в подменю

Tags: android

Элементам списка задано контекстное меню, `MenuItem.getMenuInfo()` для элементов корневого меню работает как положено, но для элементов подменю выдаёт `null`.
При этом в `onContextItemSelected()` нет никакой возможности получить ссылку на элемент, которому принадлежит подменю или к самому меню.
Так как же тогда получить информацию об элементе списка, для которого меню было вызвано?
меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/root_item_1"
        android:title="root_item_1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/root_item_2"
        android:title="root_item_2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/root_item_3"
        android:title="root_item_3">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sub_item_1"
                android:title="sub_item_1" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sub_item_2"
                android:title="sub_item_2" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(@NonNull ContextMenu menu, @NonNull View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = requireActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_main, menu);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.root_item_1) {
            Log.d(TAG, item.getTitle() + ": " + item.getMenuInfo()); // root_item_1: {android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterContextMenuInfo@12345}
        } else if (itemId == R.id.sub_item_1) {
            Log.d(TAG, item.getTitle() + ": " + item.getMenuInfo()); // sub_item_1: null
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: вопрос однако хороший)) +1 :D  красивого решения как мне кажется может не получится, решил для интереса поковыряться, даже если иметь `ContextMenu`, все-равно к внутренним элементам достучаться не получается нормально. Самый быстрый вариант - сохранять в переменную историю навигации, если список будет длинным, например какую-то HashMap